# Optimize RecycleView for Chat Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have RecycleView to show Chat from local database use Room and it works fine but when I try to scroll fast it does not respond for a couple seconds.
I already try to make simple logic onBindViewHolder but still the same. its because I use View.GONE and View.Visible in time group? how can I make this faster when scroll and I load data from local with limit 100.

this my Adapter using SortedList

```
class ContentAdapter(private val userUid: String, private val mListener: (code: Int, data: Content)->Unit): ExperimentalAdapter<Content, ContentAdapter.Holder>() {
  private var lastDateTime: DateTime = DateFactory().getDateTimeDefaultTimezone()
  private var lastPosition = 0

  init {
    mData = SortedListAsync(
      Content::class.java,
      object : SortedListAsyncAdapterCallback<Content>(this) {
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Content?, newItem: Content?): Boolean {
          if(oldItem!!.dateTime == null){
            oldItem.calculateDateTime()
          }
          if(newItem!!.dateTime == null){
            newItem.calculateDateTime()
          }
          return oldItem.content == newItem.content &&
              oldItem.status == newItem.status &&
              oldItem.createdAt == newItem.createdAt
        }

        override fun areItemsTheSame(item1: Content?, item2: Content?): Boolean {
          if(item1!!.dateTime == null){
            item1.calculateDateTime()
          }
          if(item2!!.dateTime == null){
            item2.calculateDateTime()
          }
          return item1.uid == item2.uid
        }

        override fun compare(o1: Content?, o2: Content?): Int {
          if(o1!!.dateTime == null){
            o1.calculateDateTime()
          }
          if(o2!!.dateTime == null){
            o2.calculateDateTime()
          }
          return o2.createdAt.toDateTime().millis
            .compareTo(o1.createdAt.toDateTime().millis)
        }
      })

    setHasStableIds(true)
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
    val timeExec = measureNanoTime {
      var item: Content = mData.get(position)
      var isShowTime = false
      var timeString = ""

      var itemBefore: Content? = null

      if (position != 0) {
        itemBefore = mData.get(position - 1)
      }

      if (itemBefore != null) {
        val nowDate = item.dateTime!!
        val beforeDate = itemBefore.dateTime!!

        if(item.beforeDateTime == null || item.beforeDateTime != beforeDate){
          d("do checking time")
          if (!DateFactory().isStillInOneDay(nowDate, beforeDate)) {
            when {
              DateFactory().isStillInOneDay(lastDateTime, beforeDate) -> {
                isShowTime = true
                timeString = "Today"
              }
              DateFactory().isYesterday(lastDateTime, beforeDate) -> {
                isShowTime = true
                timeString = "Yesterday"
              }
              DateFactory().isTheDayBeforeYesterday(lastDateTime, beforeDate) -> {
                isShowTime = true
                timeString = "${beforeDate.dayOfWeek().asShortText}, ${beforeDate.dayOfMonth().get()}/${beforeDate.monthOfYear().get()}/${beforeDate.year().get()}"
              }
              else -> {
                isShowTime = true
                timeString = "${beforeDate.dayOfWeek().asShortText}, ${beforeDate.dayOfMonth().get()}/${beforeDate.monthOfYear().get()}/${beforeDate.year().get()}"
              }
            }
          }

          mData.get(position).apply {
            this.timeString = timeString
            this.isShowTime = isShowTime
            this.beforeDateTime = beforeDate
          }
          item = mData.get(position)
        }else{
          d("Skip checking time")
        }
        lastPosition = position
      }

      holder.bind(item, item.isShowTime, item.timeString)
    }
    d("Time for exec ${mData.get(position).content} is $timeExec")
  }

  override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val type = mData.get(position)

    if(type.type == GlobalConfig.CONTENT_TYPE_IMAGE){
      return if (type.createdBy == userUid){
        10
      }else{
        11
      }
    }else if(type.type == GlobalConfig.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT){
      return if (type.createdBy == userUid){
        20
      }else{
        22
      }
    }
    return 99
  }

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
    d("inflate calling")
    when(viewType){
      10 -> {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_item_chat_image_mine, parent, false)
        return HolderImageMine(view, mListener)
      }
      11 -> {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_item_chat_image_other, parent, false)
        return HolderImageOther(view, mListener)
      }
      20 -> {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_item_chat_text_mine, parent, false)
        return HolderTextMine(view, mListener)
      }
      22 -> {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_item_chat_text_other, parent, false)
        return HolderTextOther(view, mListener)
      }
      else -> {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_item_chat_text_mine, parent, false)
        return HolderTextMine(view, mListener)
      }
    }
  }


  abstract class Holder(v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
    private val mTimeLastRead: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.victTVLastRead)
    private val mTimeLastIndex: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.victTVTimeIndex)
    private val mHolderView: ConstraintLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.victRoot) ?: v.findViewById(R.id.include)

    open fun bind(data: Content, isShowTime: Boolean, timeString: String){
      if (mTimeLastRead.visibility != View.GONE) mTimeLastRead.visibility = View.GONE


      if(isShowTime){
        if (mTimeLastIndex.visibility != View.VISIBLE) mTimeLastIndex.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        if(mTimeLastIndex.text != timeString) mTimeLastIndex.text = timeString
      }else{
        if(mTimeLastIndex.visibility != View.GONE) mTimeLastIndex.visibility = View.GONE

        if(mTimeLastIndex.text != timeString)  mTimeLastIndex.text = timeString
      }

      if(mTimeLastRead.visibility == View.GONE && mTimeLastIndex.visibility == View.GONE){
        if(mHolderView.visibility != View.GONE) mHolderView.visibility = View.GONE
      }else{
        if(mHolderView.visibility != View.VISIBLE) mHolderView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
      }
    }
  }

  class HolderTextMine(v: View,private val l: (code: Int, data: Content)->Unit): Holder(v){
    private val mTimeText: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatTextMineTime)
    private val mReadText: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatTextMineRead)
    private val mContentText: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatTextMineContent)

    override fun bind(data: Content, isShowTime: Boolean, timeString: String) {
      super.bind(data, isShowTime, timeString)
      mTimeText.text = data.timeContentString
      mContentText.text = data.content

      mReadText.text = data.statusText

      itemView.apply {
        setOnClickListener {
          l(ON_CLICK, data)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  class HolderTextOther(v: View,private val l: (code: Int, data: Content)->Unit): Holder(v){
    private val mTimeText: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatTextTime)
    private val mContentText: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatTextContent)

    override fun bind(data: Content, isShowTime: Boolean, timeString: String) {
      super.bind(data, isShowTime, timeString)
      mTimeText.text = data.timeContentString
      mContentText.text = data.content

      itemView.apply {
        setOnClickListener {
          l(ON_CLICK, data)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  class HolderImageMine(v: View,private val l: (code: Int, data: Content)->Unit): Holder(v){
    private val mTimeText: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatImageTime)
    private val mReadText: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatImageRead)
    private val mImageView: ImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatImageView)

    override fun bind(data: Content, isShowTime: Boolean, timeString: String) {
      super.bind(data, isShowTime, timeString)
      mTimeText.text = data.timeContentString

      if(data.status != 0) {
        val link = MediaApi().createUrlPictureContent(data.content)
        val token = SharedUtils(itemView.context).getToken()!!
        Glide.with(itemView).load(Connection.headerUrl(link, token))
          .thumbnail(0.1f).apply(
            RequestOptions().dontAnimate().dontTransform().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).override(18, 18)
        ).into(mImageView)
      }else{
        Glide.with(itemView).load(data.content).thumbnail(0.1f).apply(
            RequestOptions().dontAnimate().dontTransform().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).override(18, 18)
        ).into(mImageView)
      }

      mReadText.text = data.statusText

      itemView.apply {
        setOnClickListener {
          l(ON_CLICK, data)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  class HolderImageOther(v: View,private val l: (code: Int, data: Content)->Unit): Holder(v){
    private val mTimeText: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatImageOtherTime)
    private val mImageView: ImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.viChatImageOtherView)

    override fun bind(data: Content, isShowTime: Boolean, timeString: String) {
      super.bind(data, isShowTime, timeString)
      mTimeText.text = data.timeContentString
      val link = MediaApi().createUrlPictureContent(data.content)
      val token = SharedUtils(itemView.context).getToken()!!
      Glide.with(itemView).load(Connection.headerUrl(link, token)).thumbnail(0.1f).apply(
          RequestOptions().dontAnimate().dontTransform().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).override(18, 18)
      ).into(mImageView)

      itemView.apply {
        setOnClickListener {
          l(ON_CLICK, data)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  companion object {
    const val ON_CLICK = 1
  }
}
```

and this my RecycleView in Fragment

```
mRecycleView.apply {
  layoutManager = object :LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, true){
    override fun supportsPredictiveItemAnimations(): Boolean {
      return false
    }
  }
  this.layoutManager?.isItemPrefetchEnabled = true

  adapter = ContentAdapter(SharedUtils(context!!).getUid()!!){ code, data ->
    when(code){
      ContentAdapter.ON_CLICK -> {
        if(data.type == GlobalConfig.CONTENT_TYPE_IMAGE){
          val bundle = bundleOf(
              Pair("image", data.content)
          )
          view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_chatFragment_to_viewImageFragment, bundle)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  clearOnScrollListeners()
  addOnScrollListener(object :EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager) {
    override fun onLoadMore(current_page: Int, totalItem: Int) {
      rLaunch {
        mLoading = true
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
          viewModel.isLoading.value = true
        }
        viewModel.loadContent(totalItem)
      }
      d("Load content Chat!")
    }
  })

  itemAnimator = null

  setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
    this@ChatFragment.activity?.hideKeyboardFrom(mTextContent)
    return@setOnTouchListener false }
   }
```

this is my XML for show image message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/viChatRootImageMine"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/viChatRoomImageCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#dbe8ff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/viChatRootImageLayout"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viChatImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/viChatImageTime"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/white" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viChatImageTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="07:00"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/viChatImageRead" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viChatImageRead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="R"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

  <include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/view_item_chat_time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space4" />

  <Space
    android:id="@+id/space4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viChatRoomImageCard" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this for show text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/viChatTextMineRoot"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent">

  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/viChatTextMineCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#dbe8ff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/viChatTextMineLayout"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viChatTextMineTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="07:00"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/viChatTextMineRead" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viChatTextMineRead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="R"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viChatTextMineTime"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viChatTextMineContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:text="Rofie Sagara"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/viChatTextMineTime"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" />

      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="22dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

  <include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/view_item_chat_time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/space" />

  <Space
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viChatTextMineCard" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: See [this article](https://medium.com/@farshidabazari/improve-recyclerview-performance-ede5cec6c5bf)

Comment: Thanks @FarshidABZ idk if ConstraintLayout so slow in RecycleView

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @FarshidABZ
Change ConstraintLayout to Linear make more fast in RecycleView
see this [article](https://medium.com/@farshidabazari/improve-recyclerview-performance-ede5cec6c5bf)